Flutter cant open default mail app in android
I'm using flutter_email_sender and it's not finding my mail app.

PlatformException(not_available, No email clients found!, null, null).

This is my code:
  static Future<void> sendPrefilledEmail({
    required String filename,
    required List<int> bytes,
  }) async {
    // Generate a String with the path.
    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String filePath = '${directory.path}/$filename';

    // Generate the file.
    final file = File(filePath);

    // Let the callback write data to the file.
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    final Email prefilledEmail = Email(
      body: 'Diagnostic data from my device',
      subject: 'Diagnostic data from my device',
      recipients: ['support@steiner.de'],
      attachmentPaths: [file.path],
      isHTML: false,
    );

    await FlutterEmailSender.send(prefilledEmail);

  }

This is my AndroidManifest.xml
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

